# Data Structure behind LDAP Database

Tags: database, data-structures, ldap

What kind of Computer Data Structure is being used internally in a LDAP Database? Is it Binary Tree, B+ tree or Trei or something else?

Comment: I have a feeling it's implementation specific...and consists of a multitude of data structures....

Comment: @CHris Thompson: agreed - the only thing that is standardized here is the LDAP interface to the outside world. What each vendor uses internally is totally vendor-specific and probably not publicly available information...

Comment: @Mitch No Specific reason. The product I work for use LDAP db to store mobile phone subscriber related data. The number of subscribers may be as big as 3-4 millions. I was just curious about the internal data structure behind LDAP, since the read (search) operation is very fast here.

Answer (score 3):

LDAP remember is a *protocol*. Think about it this way, HTTP is a protocol, but the data could be stored on ext3, or on NFTS, or could be generated on the fly from a relational database, or it could even be some completely other device, such as in the case of a webcam. As a client, all you know is that you send HTTP requests and receive HTTP responses.

It would make sense if the underlying data store was itself a tree structure, but this can be done relationally with a self-join.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which backend server you are using to service LDAP requests.

Microsoft Active Directory is using an evolution of the Exchange database as the backend. 
Novell eDirectory using the FLAIM database as the backend.
Lotus Notes/Domino can service LDAP against its database structure.
Oracle directory uses an Oracle DB in the backend (Go figure).
OpenLDAP I am not sure.
SunOne I am not sure.

Comment: openldap can use the database you want, bdb derivate by default if I remember well